# iOS 9: get CNContact country code and phone number

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get the country code and phone number from CNContact on iOS 9. I tried many things but couldn't find a way. The best result I achieved is printing:

```
<CNPhoneNumber: 0x7f886389a140: countryCode=us, digits=5555648583>
```

Here's how I do that:

```
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {
    print(contact.phoneNumbers.count)
    for number: CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers {
        print(number.value)
    }
}
```

What I want is the values for countryCode and digits. Any ideas how to access them in Swift? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't get them since they are private.

```
let numberValue = number.value

let countryCode = numberValue.valueForKey("countryCode") as? String
let digits = numberValue.valueForKey("digits") as? String
```

This works but if you do something in this lines **your app will most likely be rejected.**

You can see all the nice stuff you could use [here](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/Contacts.framework/CNPhoneNumber.h).

If you don't plan on uploading your app to the store the solution above is OK, otherwise I'd stick with some kind of regex knowing it can break in the future:

```
countryCode=(\w{2}),.*digits=(.+)>$
```

Comment: Please don't use forced unwrap, you'll get a crash if the value is `nil`

Comment: Thank you! Probably that's why I couldn't find a solution. I'll use the regex for now.

Comment: @fpg1503 `valueForKey` is a legal method call, you should not get rejected if you use it.

Comment: It violates the review guideline 2.5. Objective-C is a dynamic language so you'll be able to access pretty much anything you want to. The value he is querying is undocumented and **should not** be used in production code as it may change on future version without any warning.

Comment: Actually `NSObject.value(forKey:)` **is public**. What is not public is the key `"digits"`. Anyway, I know the app using this which successfully approved several times, so it's *reasonably* safe.

Comment: Actually, the regex should be `\+[0-9]{1,3}` as country codes may have 1, 2 or 3 numbers.

Comment: Actually, that's a string country code (i.e `us`, `es`), has the return of this method changed?

Answer (score 7):

`Objective-C:`

```
[number.value valueForKey:@"countryCode"]
```

`Swift:`

```
number.value.valueForKey("countryCode") as? String
```

`valueForKey` is not private, and your app will not get rejected.

Comment: can you comment on how it's not private? Per fpg1503, it seems to violate guideline 2.5 because it's not documented. I'd love you to be right, just would like to know for sure! Thanks.

Comment: you WILL get rejected if you use this, if you don't you're lucky but that violates Apple guidelines

Comment: its giving IN not +91 :(

Answer (score 0):

They two members can be accessed via `valueForKey`:

```
let countryCode = number.valueForKey("countryCode") as? String
let digits = number.valueForKey("digits") as? String
```

Please note that due to the fact that these two fields are part of a private API, there's no guarantee that in the future versions of the `Contacts` framework they won't be removed/replaced.

Answer (score 0):

/* Get only first mobile number */

```
    let MobNumVar = (contact.phoneNumbers[0].value as! CNPhoneNumber).valueForKey("digits") as! String
    print(MobNumVar)
```

/* Get all mobile number */

```
    for ContctNumVar: CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers
    {
        let MobNumVar  = (ContctNumVar.value as! CNPhoneNumber).valueForKey("digits") as? String
        print(MobNumVar!)
    }
```

/* Get mobile number with mobile country code */

```
    for ContctNumVar: CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers
    {
        let FulMobNumVar  = ContctNumVar.value as! CNPhoneNumber
        let MccNamVar = FulMobNumVar.valueForKey("countryCode") as? String
        let MobNumVar = FulMobNumVar.valueForKey("digits") as? String

        print(MccNamVar!)
        print(MobNumVar!)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
fetch contacts without country code, spaces ,braces and dash  from contacts book with contact picker and textfield both 
*********** without country code

 import ContactsUI
 var phoneString:String!

    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
            let numbers = contact.phoneNumbers.first
            let a = (numbers?.value)?.stringValue ?? ""
            let myString = a
            let formattedString = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
            let newFormattedString = formattedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
            let formatstring = newFormattedString.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
            let  last10  = formatstring.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
            phoneString = String(last10.suffix(10))
            phonetextField.text = phoneString
            
        }
        
        func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
       @IBAction func inviteButton(_ sender : Any)
        {
            if phoneString == nil{
                phoneString =  phonetextField.text! //fetching from phonetextfield
                Phone = phoneString
            }
            else  {
                Phone = phoneString //fetching from phone contacts
            
            }
          }
```

Comment: At least some explanations needed for such a code blob. Also, i think the OP wanted to extract the country code and the phone number as separate entities ..

Answer (score -2):

To get Country code you can use this:

```
(contact.phoneNumbers[0].value ).value(forKey: "countryCode") as! String
```

in for loop, and key; "digits" is to get full phone number.