# Firebase database & check against phone contacts ios

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I have a dilemma.

I have a sign up system using Firebase for phone auth, and it also stores the phone number in the database with the country code. So for example in the UK +44 7729346128.

It loops through the phone book well and would look for the number with the country code, however not everyone in peoples contact book is going to have the country code. For the uk, it might just be formatted: 07729346128 rather than +44 7729346128

What is the best way to go about his?

Comment: remove the +44 and then and add a 0 in the beginning and then check for the number.

Comment: What about other countries, do they all start with a 0 after the calling code?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730543/ios-9-get-cncontact-country-code-and-phone-number) question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, Firebase Phone authentification send SMS message to confirm when user register. So the phone number must be correct in order to received this activation SMS. In many apps (like Uber, Grab...), they ask user to choose the country and then enter the phone number. Combining both info, you can create a correct phone number. Hope this helps.